# php mysql programming issue for login page

Tags: php, html, mysql

After clicking on the login button it remains on the same page and it does not give nay output for example:if i put in a wrong userid or password it should echo something but it does not echo anything and stays the same
the code for LOGIN.PHP FILE is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>    
<head>    
<meta charset="utf-8">       
<title>title of the document</title>   


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action"signin.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username"><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="PAssword"><br>
        <button type="submit">SIGN IN</button><br>
      </form>
      <br><br><br><br>
      <form action="signup1.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname"><br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname"><br>
        <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username"><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="PAssword"><br>
        <button type="submit">SIGN UP</button><br>
        </form>
      </body>
     </html>
```

the signin.php file is:

```
<?php
   include 'dbh1.php';
    $userid=$_POST['uid'];
    $pwd=$_POST['password'];
    $sql="select * from userlogin where uid='$userid' AND password='$pwd'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
   if (!$row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
      echo "YOU ARE NOT LOGGED IN INCORRECT CREDENTIALS!!";
    }
    else {
      echo "SUCCESFULLY LOGGED IN!!";
    }
```

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: You must be storing PLAIN TEXT passwords. **That is a bad practice** PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: Do a GOOGLE on `How to Create a Login Page in PHP` and read a few tutorials

Comment: kindly tell me the error !! m just a beginner

Comment: Kindly, do a little research for yourself. Thats what we all have to do when we are beginners

Comment: actually i have researched a lot for the pst few hours but m not able to solve it any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

Comment: actually what i want is to display loginsuucesfull or insuccesfull login messages after clicking in the signin button but it does not display anything !thats the problem

Comment: help asap please

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it is working. Here learn prepared statements

```
<form action"signin.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username"><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="PAssword"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
</form>

<?php
    include 'database.php';
    $userid=$_POST['uid'];
    $pwd=$_POST['password'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from userlogin where uid=? AND password=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$userid, $pwd);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $stmt->close();
```

With prepared statements you have achieved a lot of things. Just try to check it.

Comment: as i am beginner kindly tell me with the thingls i have used in my code

Comment: Sure bhai jaan! Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked :)

Comment: And forget `mysql_query` learn prepared statements. They are easy and best. You have the basic code. Learn from it